# How to click a button using selenium and draw on a canvas in python?

Tags: python, selenium

so I am trying to automate a program that would log in to a google account I created, go to this [canvas website](https://canvas.apps.chrome/), and draw a circle,
(Circle just as a placeholder because im trying to make it draw some cool stuff like a car, just to test if it will work first.) But the main issue is when you first go into the website, there is a pop up that displays and that pop up has 2 options, "learn more" and "Get started". I tried to make selenium click on the "Get started" using  `driver.find_element_by_id('Get-started').click` but it does not seem to work, I also tried to use CSS selector but that does not seem to work either. So, I'm stuck on this. Any advice or help to click the get started button? (Feel free to also give me advice on how to draw in the canvas as well!)
Here's the HTML:

```html
<paper-button id="get-started" dialog-confirm="" class="primary" aria-label="Get started" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" elevation="0" aria-disabled="false">
        Get started
      </paper-button>
```

here's the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from PrivateInfo import*

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")

link = "https://www.google.com/"

driver.get(link)

def linkText(element):
    button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(element)
    button.click()

def byClass(className):
    button2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name(className)
    button2.click()



def type(text, elements):
    input = driver.find_elements_by_name(elements)
    for element in input:
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        element.send_keys(text)



linkText("Sign in")
type(email, "identifier")
byClass("VfPpkd-vQzf8d")
type(pw, "password")


driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.get("https://canvas.apps.chrome/")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('paper-button[id="get-started"]').click()
```

edit: I also tried this

```py
getStart = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('paper-button[id="get-started"]')
for start in getStart:
    start.click()
```

it doesn't give me any errors but it does not do anything.
Ah yeah, forgot to mention but im new to using selenium.

Comment: Don't use reserved keyword (`type`, `input`). They are used by the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the popup is nested inside shadowRoots.

More on ShadowRoot [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot):

> The ShadowRoot interface of the Shadow DOM API is the root node of a
> DOM subtree that is rendered separately from a document's main DOM
> tree.

To be able to control the element you will need to switch between DOMs. Here's how:

```
drawing_app_el = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'drawing-app'))
```

This code will retrieve the `drawing_app` first and then return the content of the shadowRoot.

To have access to the button `getStarted`, here's how:

```
# Get the shadowRoot of drawing-app
drawing_app_el = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'drawing-app'))

# Get the shadowRoot of welcome-dialog within drawing_app
welcome_dialog_el = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", drawing_app_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'welcome-dialog'))

# Get the paper-dialog from welcome_dialog
paper_dialog_el = welcome_dialog_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'paper-dialog')

# Finally, retrieve the getStarted button
get_started_button = paper_dialog_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#get-started')
get_started_button.click()
```

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand this answer, but in simplified terms, what does shadowRoot do? or like, what is shadowRoot? is it like a container? like a class? that stores the HTML stuff?

Comment: where can I learn more about shadowRoot as a complete beginner?

Comment: When i Run the code to have access to the getStarted, i get this error. 
"welcome_dialog_el = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", drawing_app_el.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'welcome-dialog'))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_elements'"

Comment: I forgot to to mention that I just start doing small projects in Selenium so I'm a beginner to that, but I know a bit of HTML., I don't know any javascript. @Nic Laforge

Comment: I have provided a link where you can read about shadow elements, plus I cited the definition. As for your error, you have added a `s` to `find_elements`. Which would return a list. Use it without `s` to get a single element (like in the code I provided)